# Search does not find all matches

Tags: search

I have a problem configuring search on my site using Custom Search as well as Search Autocomplete. I set the both modules' options to include only 2 types of content. Within those types I have 4 nodes with titles matching the pattern: `ABC-....` which are presented as autocomplete item. However when I enter `ABC` and press enter, only one of those node is found. What could be the cause?

Comment: Please keep one question per question.

Comment: I have split my post, sorry.